# Class with struct in it.. C++

Tags: c++, struct, invoice

I have a class

```
class piet3 : public Pieteikums
{
public:
piet3();
virtual ~piet3();
void set_invoice(string nDate, float nPrice);

protected:

private:
struct invoice
{
    string date;
    float price;
};
invoice arr[30];

};
```

my cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "piet3.h"

using namespace std;

piet3::piet3()
{

}

piet3::~piet3()
{

}

void piet3::set_invoice(string nDate, float nPrice)
{
struct invoice.date = nDate;
}
```

Basically what im trying to do is. I would like to get user input of price they spent and which date it happened and put it all in array as struct.

Like arr[0] = struct1, arr[1] = struct2.

I know they problem is with invoice but I cant figure it out.

main:

```
//everything before is declared
piet3 object;
cin >> date;
cin >> price;
object.set_invoice (date,price);
```

Comment: `piet3 object;` To use piet3, you need a object. Why do you think using `invoice` without object is ok?

Comment: so I should go with piet3* object = new piet3(); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is here (invalid syntax):

```
void piet3::set_invoice(string nDate, float nPrice)
{
  struct invoice.date = nDate;
}
```

You should have something like:

```
void piet3::set_invoice(string nDate, float nPrice)
{
  arr[lines].date = nDate;
  arr[lines].price = nPrice;

  ++lines;
}
```

`lines` is a new private data member to be added for counting the records of the invoice.

Better yet, you can use a [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of the raw array:

```
#include <vector>
// ...
private:
  struct invoice
  {
    string date;
    float price;
  };

  vector<invoice> arr;
};  // class piet3
```

you haven't to add the `lines` data member and you don't have the `30` records limit for invoice:

```
void piet3::set_invoice(string nDate, float nPrice)
{
  arr.push_back({nDate, nPrice});
}
```

Also consider that for a real software `float` / `double` can cause significant accounting problems.

Comment: Thanks!
for getter I should just use vector.at right?

Comment: @osiic21 [`vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) or [`vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at). Usually you'll resort to a "foreach" statement: `for (auto &record : arr) { /* use / update record */ }`